# Ordering a data frame by group only outputting the first n values

Tags: r, performance

I have a data frame containing the statistic measure for thousands of classifications. The data features a number of different classes. I output the data frame ordered by first the class and then the measures:

`statia[order(statia$class, -statia$MCC, -statia$ROC_Area, -statia$F.Measure),]`

Is there an easy way to modify the command, so that I don't get all rows, but of each class the first n rows, ergo the n ones with the highest MMC value?

**Edit:**

As criticized in the comments, I try to come up with an example. I hope it will help to prevent future confusion. However @beginneR's answer was what I was looking for. I will try to make my questions more clear in future.

```
1              file           class     MCC ROC_Area F.measure
2          run1.txt     Iris-setosa    0.98        0         1
3          run1.txt Iris-versicolor    0.92     0.06     0.885
4          run1.txt  Iris-virginica     0.9     0.04     0.918
5          run1.txt   Weighted_Avg.   0.933    0.033     0.934
6          run3.txt     Iris-setosa       1        0         1
7          run3.txt Iris-versicolor       1        0         1
8          run3.txt  Iris-virginica       1        0         1
9          run3.txt   Weighted_Avg.       1        0         1
10         [...]
```

What I wanted was (as more nicely shown in the solution):
Example: Of each class the 3 samples with the highest MCC value:

```
1              file           class     MCC ROC_Area F.measure
2          run3.txt     Iris-setosa       1        0         1
3          run1.txt     Iris-setosa    0.98        0         1
4          run5.txt     Iris-setosa    0.60        0         1
5          run3.txt Iris-versicolor       1        0         1
6          run1.txt Iris-versicolor    0.92     0.06     0.885
7          [...]
```

Comment: Have you tried `?head`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg there is more than 1 class so you still need to split the frames

Comment: @Calimo, he didn't provide any data ir desired output so I probably misunderstood the question

Comment: @DavidArenburg while I agree taking the time to provide data / reproducible example is polite and can sometime help solving the question, I think in this case it is 1) obvious from the question that there is more than 1 class and 2) easy enough to answer the question without data.

Comment: @Calimo, I disagree. Fact is, that beginneR had to create some data in order to solve this. No one else didn't even bother

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
statiaNew <- statia %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    arrange(class, desc(MCC), desc(ROC_Area), desc(F.Measure)) %>%
    do(head(., 10))    # to show the first 10 rows per class
```

Update:

If you prefer a base R alternative:

```
statiaNew <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(statia, statia$class), function(x){
  head(x[with(x, order(class, -MCC, -ROC_Area, -F.Measure)),], 10) #return first 10 rows
}))
```

Or

```
statia <- statia[order(statia$class, -statia$MCC, -statia$ROC_Area, -statia$F.Measure),]
statiaNew  <- statia[ave(statia$class, statia$class, FUN = seq_along) <= 10, ]
```

---

Update 2: here's how those approaches perform on the `iris` data set:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  arrange(Species, desc(Sepal.Length), desc(Sepal.Width), desc(Petal.Length)) %>%
  do(head(., 3))    

#Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
#Groups: Species
#
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
#2          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#3          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa
#4          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#5          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#6          6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
#7          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
#8          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
#9          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(iris, iris$Species), function(x){
  head(x[with(x, order(Species, -Sepal.Length, -Sepal.Width, -Petal.Length)),], 3)
}))

#              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#setosa.15              5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
#setosa.16              5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#setosa.19              5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa
#versicolor.51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#versicolor.53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#versicolor.77          6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
#virginica.132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
#virginica.118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
#virginica.136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica

iris <- iris[with(iris, order(Species, -Sepal.Length, -Sepal.Width, -Petal.Length)),]
iris[ave(as.numeric(iris$Species), iris$Species, FUN = seq_along) <= 3, ]

#note that I used `as.numeric(iris$Species)` because it's stored as `factor`s and would cause an error otherwise.

#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
#16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#19           5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa
#51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#77           6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
#132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
#118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
#136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica
```

Comment: Are you again providing a solution to an imaginary data without any proof that your code even works ?:)

Comment: I have no doubts. I just think that we shouldn't attempt to answer questions when the OP didn't do the minimal effort of providing a reproducible example and desired output, for two reasons. 1- If he wouldn't bother to help himself, why should we. 2- you can't truly know how his data looks like and what exactly he wants, and may find yourself in a long chain of comments with the OP when he says that this is not what he wanted, and you trying to provide alternative solutions etc. It's just waste of time and effort and not constructive.

Comment: @DavidArenburg the structure of the data is sufficiently clear to answer the question beyond doubt, there is no ambiguity. You can't call the data imaginary: it is self explaining. As for 1, beginneR decided to answer, that's his problem.

Comment: If I asked my question unclear in any way, I beg your pardon. Although it's late now, I provided an example now. I hope this meets your critique, @DavidArenburg. Anyway I hope it will at least help anyone reading this question later. Thanks to beginnR, the answer was what I was looking for.